# MySQL - Select from multiple columns and ignore duplicate results

Tags: php, mysql

I want to run a SELECT statement which takes 4 different columns, lets call them col1, col2, col3, col4 and displays all of the text in alphabetical order from each one while ignoring any duplicates.

For example, the table contains the following data.

```
 col1   |   col2     |   col3    |   col4   
===============================================
animal  |            |           |
create  |   animal   |           |
destroy |            |           |
 giant  |   create   |  animal   |
create  |   destroy  |   belt    |
animal  |   giant    |  animal   |  create  
animal  |            |           |
```

The expected result should be:

- animal
- belt
- create
- destroy
- giant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html):

```
SELECT col1 FROM tab
UNION
SELECT col2 FROM tab
UNION
SELECT col3 FROM tab
UNION
SELECT col4 FROM tab
ORDER BY col1
```

**EDIT:**

To avoid `NULL` and empty string:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT col1 FROM tab
    UNION
    SELECT col2 FROM tab
    UNION
    SELECT col3 FROM tab
    UNION
    SELECT col4 FROM tab) sub
WHERE sub.col1 IS NOT NULL AND sub.col1 <> ''
ORDER BY col1;
```

Comment: Only problem with this is that it puts `NULL` into the list. You might want to add `WHERE colx IS NOT NULL` to the individual selects.

Comment: @Nick Yes, I am aware that it will return single `NULL`/`''`. I didn't added any kind of filtering because I was not sure it is actual `NULL` or empty string. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Good point I had assumed it was `NULL` but it could also be an empty string